# How do I unmarshal nested XML elements into an array?

Tags: xml, go, unmarshalling

My XML contains an array of predefined elements, but I can't pick up the array.  Here is the XML structure:

```
var xml_data = `<Parent>
                   <Val>Hello</Val>
                   <Children>
                      <Child><Val>Hello</Val></Child>
                      <Child><Val>Hello</Val></Child>
                      <Child><Val>Hello</Val></Child>
                   </Children>
                </Parent>`
```

Here is the full code and here is the [playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/VfHDqKILfA).  Running this will pick up Parent.Val, but not Parent.Children.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/xml"
)

func main() {

    container := Parent{}
    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(xml_data), &container)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(container)  
    }
}

var xml_data = `<Parent>
                   <Val>Hello</Val>
                   <Children>
                      <Child><Val>Hello</Val></Child>
                      <Child><Val>Hello</Val></Child>
                      <Child><Val>Hello</Val></Child>
                   </Children>
                </Parent>`

type Parent struct {
    Val string
    Children []Child
}

type Child struct {
    Val string
}
```

EDIT: I simplified the problem a bit [here](https://play.golang.org/p/JkaA79p1-W).  Basically I can't unmarshal any array, not just of predefined structure.  Below is the updated work code.  In that example, only one item ends up in the container interface.

```
func main() {

    container := []Child{}
    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(xml_data), &container)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(container)  
    }

    /* 
        ONLY ONE CHILD ITEM GETS PICKED UP
    */
}

var xml_data = `
            <Child><Val>Hello</Val></Child>
            <Child><Val>Hello</Val></Child>
            <Child><Val>Hello</Val></Child>
        `

type Child struct {
    Val string
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this kind of nesting, you'll need also a struct for `Children` element:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/xml"
)

func main() {

    container := Parent{}
    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(xml_data), &container)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(container)  
    }
}

var xml_data = `<Parent>
            <Val>Hello</Val>
            <Children>
                <Child><Val>Hello</Val></Child>
                <Child><Val>Hello</Val></Child>
                <Child><Val>Hello</Val></Child>
            </Children>
        </Parent>`

type Parent struct {
    Val string
    Children Children
}

type Children struct {
    Child []Child
}

type Child struct {
    Val string
}
```

Also pasted here: [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/-rNryBSq01)

Note that your code would work (after changing variable name from `Children` to `Child`) with this kind of XML structure:

```
<Parent>
    <Val>Hello</Val>
    <Child><Val>Hello</Val></Child>
    <Child><Val>Hello</Val></Child>
    <Child><Val>Hello</Val></Child>
</Parent>
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  Can you please show me what it would look like in the simplified example from my edit?  I'm applying your solution but it doesn't work.  Here is the playground: https://play.golang.org/p/cXG6prczVK

Comment: according to the principle you explained, the first example should work

Comment: i believe that in this case the issue might be, that XML must have only one top-level element - i.e. your XML input in the second example is not valid XML

Comment: @believesInSanta, you can avoid a separate struct for nested elements [by using a specially crafted tag](https://play.golang.org/p/7aGWd0Crnb). Please actually take your time and read the rules for XML unmarshaling explained [here](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Unmarshal): the `encoding/xml` package has some power tools which might not be obvious from just skimming over random examples found in the internets ;-)

Comment: oh wow, I didn't realize the full utility of those tags.  thanks a lot for showing me that @kostix

Answer (score 34):

```
type Parent struct {
    Val string
    Children []Child  `xml:"Children>Child"`  //Just use the '>'
}
```

Comment: This is a better less cluttered solution, and confirmed to work: https://play.golang.org/p/K4WhGBJnfp

Comment: Yeah, this is what I needed as well. Otherwise, for a similar case, the accepted solution was leaving me with a redundant node/struct in my xml-to-json transformation. @snyh

Comment: Thank you! This should be accepted as a correct answer.