# How can I get data from nested xml which doesn't use end tag in repeat items?

Tags: xml, go, struct, slice, unmarshalling

According to the below link, we can get data from nested xml by using `>` or another struct.

[How do I unmarshal nested XML elements into an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34941539/how-do-i-unmarshal-nested-xml-elements-into-an-array/42618835)

However it doesn't work in case of not using end tag like this.

code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/xml"
)

func main() {

    container := Parent{}
    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(xml_data), &container)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(container)  
    }
}

var xml_data = `<Parent>
            <Val>Hello</Val>
                <Child Val="Hello"/>
                <Child Val="Hello"/>
                <Child Val="Hello"/>
        </Parent>`

type Parent struct {
    Val string
    Children Children
}

type Children struct {
    Child []Child
}

type Child struct {
    Val string
}
```

result:

```
{Hello {[]}}
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 7):

`<Child>` in your XML is a "child" of `Parent`, so get rid of the `Children` wrapper struct, the slice should be a field of `Parent`. Also the values in `<Child>` are in attributes, so you have to use the `,attr` option.

Working model:

```
type Parent struct {
    Val   string
    Child []Child
}

type Child struct {
    Val string `xml:",attr"`
}
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/gJ84ZA0jME_w)):

```
{Hello [{Hello} {Hello} {Hello}]}
```

Comment: Shame on me. Thank you ! The end tag had nothing to do with my error. `,attr` is also key point.